# How do I get OpenCart to load resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencart, bitnami

We have deployed a staging version of Bitnami OpenCart 2.3.0.2-1 in an AWS instance version. The config files have this setup:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8089/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8089/');
```

When I load the site, the images do not display and the CSS does not render. But if I inspect an img tag, the src attribute points to an existing image. For example:

```
<img src="http://staging.abc.com/image/catalog/ABC_images/abc_logo.png" title="ABC Services" alt="ABC Services" class="img-responsive">
```

When I copy/paste http://staging.abc.com/image/catalog/ABC_images/abc_logo.png on the browser, the image loads. Is there any AWS or OpenCart settings we need to adjust?

Comment: As per data provided I can see server variable with https but image url with http please check that both have https

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, we have a tool that helps you configure your domain in the application. Can you run this command in the command line `sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain your_domain_here`. You can find more information about this [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/opencart/administration/update-ip-hostname/)